# Website subdomain redirect in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, iis, url-rewriting

I have 2 virtual directories in my `IIS 7.5`. These need to be accessed like they are subdomains.

Ex.

My domain: `mydomain.com`

Directory 1: `dir1.mydomain1.com`

Directory 2: `dir2.mydomain1.com`

Also I need to force `https` scheme when user tries with `http`. I added rule in my `web.config` file of first application as:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It works when required URL was `http://mydomain1.com/dir1`. URL changes to `https://mydomain1.com/dir1` Please help me regarding subdomain rule.

Comment: Have you tried to add a new binding for Https in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work for redirecting from a subdomain. However, 'www' would be considered a subdomain, so you should probably handle that one prior to the subdomain redirect.

```
<rule name="Redirect www to nonwww" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.mydomain.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://mydomain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>

<rule name="RedirectSubdomain" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*).mydomain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mydomain.com/{C:1}" />
</rule>
```

Your force https rule can go last, after these 2 rules.